# Postman and cURL is returning different output

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, curl, postman

This is url I'm running in the postman :- `http://213.252.244.214/create-signature.php`. It has two parameters `string` and `key`. It will return `input` which you have entered and the output which is `RJAGDhoz8yDJ7GwVLberI/NMYy2zMTTeR9YzXj7QhCM=` but if I run it from the curl then it is returning `D9UmS6r/qg0QI/0eIakifqrM3Nd1g6B3W7RCsiyO7sc=`. The output is in JSON Format. Following is the cURL code:-

```
public function create_signature($input, $key) {
        $ch = curl_init();    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://213.252.244.214/create-signature.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "string=$input&key=$key");                   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $json = json_decode($output);
        $signature = $json->output; echo $signature; echo '<br>';
        curl_close($ch);
        return $signature;
    }
```

sample string is:- `2019-01-23 14:00:594lzUTYHw01dW5EmPan01M07hEiWUaEmdKl3kzpUUqak=Ha2wZwz46l7vSboxVNx3/DAUYsInjjKtAbDSnPsdDnA=igK7XzaTBrusPc3q5OEOQg==igK7XzaTBrusPc3q5OEOQg==1.0.110671523012111548248459fR9b/McBCzk=Deposit Fund698EURLuisTurinTurinVenis13212TF990303274103325689667lg@gmail.comLuisTurinTurinVenis13212TF990303274103325689667lg@gmail.comLuisTurinTurinVenis13212TF990303274103325689667lg@gmail.comclient_deposithttp://localhost/feature/CD-716/gateways/certus_finance/paymenthttp://localhost/feature/CD-716/gateways/certus_finance/paymenthttp://localhost/feature/CD-716/gateways/certus_finance/payment`

sample key is :- `85e1d7a5e2d22e46`

Can anyone tell me why is it different?? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$input` and `$key` values are not being encoded. From the `curl_setopt()` [manual page](http://php.net/manual/function.curl-setopt.php#refsect1-function.curl-setopt-parameters)...

> This parameter can either be passed as a **urlencoded string** ... or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value

Postman does this by default.

To save yourself having to manually encode strings, just use the array method

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'input' => $input,
    'key'   => $key
]);
```

---

Take note of this caveat though...

> **Note:**
>   Passing an array to **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS** will encode the data as *multipart/form-data*, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*.

If required, to ensure `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you can build an encoded string using [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/function.http-build-query.php), eg

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
    'input' => $input,
    'key'   => $key
]));
```